# Folder Permission details for folders\sub folders

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions, directory

I want to extract a folder and its sub folders permission details.

My server is Windows 2008, I use Windows PowerShell script but getting below error.

```
Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Directory'.
At line:1 char:5
+ dir -Directory -Path "H:\RMSRE7\RMS1" -Recurse -Force
+     ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

PowerShell script:

```
$FolderPath = dir -Directory -Path "\\H:\RMSRE7" -Recurse -Force
$Report = @()
foreach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
    foreach ($Access in $acl.Access) {
        $Properties = [ordered]@{
            'FolderName'       = $Folder.FullName;
            'AD Group or User' = $Access.IdentityReference;
            'Permissions'      = $Access.FileSystemRights;
            'Inherited'        = $Access.IsInherited
        }
        $Report += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
    }
}
$Report | Export-Csv -Path "D:\Public\RE7_FolderPermissions.csv"
```

Comment: Which version of PowerShell?  `-Directory` and `-File` are not part of the filesystem provider in early versions - not sure exactly when they were introduced, but probably v3.

Comment: Correct. The parameters were added with version 3, so the OP is most likely running PowerShell v2.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell v2 (which is what you seem to be using) the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet doesn't have a parameter `-Directory`. That was introduced with PowerShell v3.

If you want to restrict the results of `Get-ChildItem` to directories you need to use a `Where-Object` filter prior to PowerShell v3, e.g.:

```
$FolderPath = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\H:\RMSRE7" -Recurse -Force |
              Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }
```

The `[ordered]` type accelerator also isn't available prior to PowerShell v3, so you need to remove it from your code.

```
$Properties = [ordered]@{
    'FolderName'       = $Folder.FullName;
    'AD Group or User' = $Access.IdentityReference;
    'Permissions'      = $Access.FileSystemRights;
    'Inherited'        = $Access.IsInherited
}
```

If you want to ensure a particular order of fields in the output CSV you can pipe the data through `Select-Object` before the export. And you may want to add the parameter `-NoType` to `Export-Csv` to avoid the object type comment at the beginning of the output file.

```
$Report |
    Select-Object FolderName, 'AD Group or User', Permissions, Inherited |
    Export-Csv -Path "D:\Public\RE7_FolderPermissions.csv" -NoType
```

Comment: To restrict to directories only, shouldn't that be `Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }`

Comment: @Theo Of course it should. Thanks for the heads up. Fixed.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers : I modified as Ansgar said, but I am getting another warning as shown below.

Comment: PS D:\test\permission> .\myscript.ps1
Unable to find type [ordered]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At D:\test\permission\myscript.ps1:7 char:36
+             $Properties = [ordered] <<<< @{'FolderName'=$Folder.FullName;'AD
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ordered:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

Comment: New-Object : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Property'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that i
s not null or empty and then try the command again.
At D:\test\permission\myscript.ps1:10 char:63
+             $Report += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property <<<<  $Properties
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: @Purushothaman See updated answer. Also, please do not post things like that in comments, b/c they become unreadable. Edit your question if you need to provide additional information.